# how can i pass my instance variable througout my entire activity?

Tags: java, android, variables, object

I am trying to make a custom list view adapter. In my public void function I am trying to set the adapter.. (after make the list from the web

This is in my onCreate():

```
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main, rowItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My question is: how can I make my custom listview adapter adapter variable available throughout my activity????

Here is a snippet from when i set my names city and icon and i try to set my adapter

```
item.setTitle(p.getString("name"));
item.setDesc(p.getString("city"));
item.setImageId(p.getString("icon"));
rowItems.add(item);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but eclipse can't find it. I even tried to recall the instance in the public void function with no luck....

Any suggestions?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask().execute();

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter =
        new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: In general if you implement an Application (that class!) this won't be destroyed if an activity restarts, but I'm not sure if this will help you.

Comment: Where are you setting the adapter?  In which method?  Where are you declaring the adapter?  Please show that code.

Comment: @Simon, i was setting it in my on create, but I wasn't sure if I should set it AFTER i get my list from the net, either way I cant notifyadapterchange(adapter) either since i cant get a hold of the instance later on in the activity.

Comment: maybe should be noted I am trying to reset the adapter within a private class in the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration into a class field, like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    CustomListViewAdapter adapter;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask().execute();

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main, rowItems);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

Class fields are accessible in all methods of a class.  It's all about "scope".  Declaring the adapter inside `onCreate` limits it's scope (it's visibility) to that method and classes declared within it.

BTW, you don't say why you are trying to "reset" your adapter but usually, you should only set it once.